# Rails ActiveRecord Won't Save Associations On Create But Will On Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following methods for Create and Update in my Controller:

```
  def new
    if request.post?
      @article = Article.new(article_params)
      @article.user = @user
      if @article.save
        redirect_to :admin_articles, :flash => { success: t(:article_created) }
      end
    else
      @article = Article.new
    end
  end

  def edit
    if request.patch?
      if @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to :admin_articles, :flash => { success: t(:article_updated) }
      end
    end
  end
```

And I have the following for the article_params:

```
    def article_params
        article_params = params[:article].permit(:category_id, :title, :slug, :article_type, :content, :link, :summary)
        if params[:tags].present?
          tags = params[:tags].split ','
          tags_array = Array.new
          tags.each do |t|
            tags_array.append Tag.find_or_create_by slug: t
          end

          article_params[:tags] = tags_array
        end

    article_params
  end
```

When I do the Update it saves properly, but when I try to do the Create it says *Article Tags is invalid*. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your create action? Convention!!!

Comment: Hi, is it possible to determine if a record was successfully created using the create method?

Comment: Nevermind, saw it was. I did not realize this was improper convention, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was me not understanding convention. My object had not been created therefore it did not have a tags property yet. I have changed my methods to the following:

```
    def article_params
        params[:article].permit(:category_id, :title, :slug, :article_type, :content, :link, :summary)
      end

      def tags
        tags = Array.new

        if params[:tags].present?
          tag_param_array = params[:tags].split ','
          tag_param_array.each do |t|
            tags.append Tag.find_or_create_by slug: t
          end
        end

        tags
      end

      def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.create article_params
    if @article.valid?
      @article.tags = tags

      redirect_to :admin_articles, :flash => { :success => t(:article_created) } if @article.save
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def patch
    @article.update_attributes article_params
    if @article.valid?
      @article.tags = tags

      redirect_to :admin_articles, :flash => { :success => t(:article_updated) } if @article.save
    end
  end
```

Comment: But you're still going against convention! You should really have a New and Create action to make life easier for yourself. See the intro to Rails for further info.

Comment: @tommyd456 I am confused. The Getting Started with Rails guide is showing to use the method before which you said was improper convention (.save). Can you explicitly link me a link to proper convention?

Comment: @tommyd456 I believe I understand what you meant. I have moved my create and patch logic into separate controller actions and routed them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have (or at least haven't shown) a `create` method in your controller, so you're just getting ActiveModel's default implementation which isn't going to pick up any of the params. If you're doing something non-standard with your routes, such that POST is getting mapped to `new`, please share that.

Comment: I map it like:
match 'articles/new', to: 'articles#new', via: [:get, :post], as: :article_new

Comment: Can I ask how it is that you're causing the POST to go to `articles/new` on submission (i.e. from your view)?

Comment: <%= form_for @article, { :url => :admin_article_new } do |f| %>

Comment: Can I ask why you're not following the Rails defaults?

Comment: Have you confirmed your `:url` parameter is working (i.e. that you're taking the `request.post?` branch of your if/else)?

Comment: Also (since this approach is new to me), how is `admin_article_new` getting defined?

Comment: The admin_article_new is a path defined as a nested route in my routes.

Comment: Hi guys, if I used create I can't get validation errors or determine if the record was saved.

Comment: I have updated it to use proper syntax:
@article = Article.create article_params
      if @article.valid?
        redirect_to :admin_articles, :flash => { success: t(:article_created) }
      end

But it still says tags is invalid.

Comment: I don't think the issue is that you're not using the model's `create` function. I think the issue is that you're not invoking the controller's new function in the case of POST, since `admin_article_new` presumably maps to some other method. If you want to continue with the non-standard routing, you need to fix your `:url` parameter. If we want to go to standard routing, then you need to remove the `:url` parameter and introduce a `create` method in your _controller_.